# Left positioned item on iOS gets larger on iframe

Tags: ios, css, iframe, hamburger-menu

I've implemented a simple left-pull burger menu in a mobile webpage that lives inside an iframe. However, it's behaving strangely on iPhones. We are using Bootstrap for the general page layout and stuff.

Using WeInRe I've noticed the following behaviour: in an iframe with 320px in fixed `width`, if I add, say, `left: 50px` to the `body` of the page inside it, this `body` moves `50px` to the left just fine, but also starts to display `370px` in width, instead of `320px` as before.
The problem is worse: as the correct `left` value is a percentage, the body gets that bigger width, and after that the `left` is recalculated, making the menu larger than the viewport.

What the hell is happening here? Is this some sort of known bug of Mobile Safari?

Unfortunately, there's no public available code for this issue yet...

This is the relevant code:

```css
  .offcanvas {
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
  }
  .offcanvas.active {
    left: 75%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #5c008a;
    top: 0;
    left: -75%;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
  }
 .offcanvas.active .sidebar {
    left: 0;
  }
```

```js
$('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function() {
    $('.offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```html
<body class="offcanvas">
    [...]
    <div class="sidebar">[...]</div>
    [...]
</body>
```

Here's a [sample](http://www.igorsantos.com.br/side-push-iframe.htm), based on a series of side menus from [a tutorial](http://callmenick.com/post/slide-and-push-menus-with-css3-transitions) (click the left or right push options).